# SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org failed to run

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am getting this when I retrieve code from my Org. I was able to authorize an org successfully, but when I go to the Org Browser and try to pull in data of a custom object that is when I get this error **SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org failed to run**

I saw a post suggesting to reinstall Salesforce CLI, I tried that it didn't work for me.

Please advice, I am behind on my work because of this.

This is what I see on my terminal when I right click and run retrieve from org
[image]

Comment: Could someone help me here, I am loosing a lot of time with this error.

Comment: Is this is a known issue? It was working for me till Friday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anybody experiences this issue, the workaround would be to turn off Experimental Deploy Retrieve on settings under User and workspace.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I refreshed a sandbox and tried to retrieve the sources from the org.

Before refreshing the sandbox, I had no errors at all. After refreshing, I was unable to get anything done. I reconnected with the org several times, I tried deleting sources in Visual Studio, I tried to retrieve at several levels (package.xml, directories, ...). It all led to the same not very helpful error.

Then I restarted Visual Studio. It had some error about the extension host, I restarted it. And only then was I able to retrieve the sources from the org.

Comment: I read comments saying the latest update to CLI broke it and the only workaround was to turn that experimental feature off. It took me a whole day to figure out what was actually going on, and with the workaround applied, it worked all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

Under the manifest folder, you will see package.xml file. Right click on it and choose 'SFDX: Retrieve Source in manifest from Org'. IT will run successfully without a fail. IT worked for me.

Comment: The presence of a package.xml file is not a given (`sfdx force:project:create` does not create one for you unless you specify `-x`/`--manifest`). The question itself doesn't mention a manifest file either (the "org browser" is being used), so this isn't a really good fit/solution for this particular question.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your versions match your org version API version in VisualStudio.

1. Open - https://.my.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/metadata

- The header comment will show your API version:
- Salesforce.com Metadata API version ##.0

2. In Visual Studio check the following file values -

- sfdx-project.json and check sourceApiVersion value.
- Package.xml check ##.#

You may need to restart VisualStudio after making these changes.  Additionally, I've had to go to CLI and revert to a prior version.  Most recently I had to revert from 56.5.1 to 55.4.1.
To change the CLI version go to Extension VS code >> Search for Salesforce CLI Integration >> near Uninstall button there is a drop-down >> Install another version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this as well and the solution ended up being simple, I had selected too many items to pull from my Org. I cleaned up my package.xml by only selecting what I needed (classes, flows, etc.) and the pull finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this issue, I had a file stored locally that didn't match what was in Production. I noticed this error in the Output tab:

```
\force-app\main\default\flows\Loan_Flow.flow-meta-old.xml: Could not infer a metadata type
14:14:45.401 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org
```

I didn't need the file so I deleted it and was then able to successfully Retrieve Source from Org.